# Populate a Spinner class using by entering the first letter of elements in an array

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I am supposed to create an app to generate a drop down list of states, that starts with a letter entered by user. The app should have one text input field and one button ("search"). It should also have an empty drop-down list below.

The list of all US states should be stored in an array.

Once a button clicked:
if there is a single letter entered a drop down list is populated with the states names from the array that starts with an entered
letter.   If none or more than one letter is entered, nothing should be done.

I'm so lost and confused on what to do at this point. I tried using a searchView but I'm not sure if that is even the right way to go, as it's not doing any type of filtering what so ever, if i click the button the array just shows up in the drop down, all 50 states no matter what is typed in the searchView. I'm almost wondering if I should switch to just having it be a textView... but either way, help please! (end of semester is near and my teacher though he says "ask for help" is not even bothering to respond to email... *sigh*)  Here is my code:

Content_main.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Look for States below"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search States"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
        android:queryHint="Search" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.Java:

```js
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    SearchView searchView;
    Button stateLook;
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        searchView = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        stateLook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    };



    public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
        Button button = (Button) v;
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayList states = new ArrayList();
        states.add("Alabama");
        states.add("Alaska");
        states.add("Arizona");
        states.add("Arkansas");
        states.add("California");
        states.add("Colorado");
        states.add("Connecticut");
        states.add("Delaware");
        states.add("Florida");
        states.add("Georgia");
        states.add("Hawaii");
        states.add("Idaho");
        states.add("Illinois");
        states.add("India");
        states.add("Iowa");
        states.add("Kansas");
        states.add("Kentucky");
        states.add("Louisiana");
        states.add("Maine");
        states.add("Maryland");
        states.add("Massachusetts");
        states.add("Michigan");
        states.add("Minnesota");
        states.add("Mississippi");
        states.add("Missouri");
        states.add("Montana");
        states.add("Nebraska");
        states.add("Nevada");
        states.add("New Hampshire");
        states.add("New Jersey");
        states.add("New Mexico");
        states.add("New York");
        states.add("North Carolina");
        states.add("North Dakota");
        states.add("Ohio");
        states.add("Oklahoma");
        states.add("Oregon");
        states.add("Pennsylvania");
        states.add("Rhode Island");
        states.add("South Carolina");
        states.add("South Dakota");
        states.add("Tennessee");
        states.add("Texas");
        states.add("Utah");
        states.add("Vermont");
        states.add("Virgina");
        states.add("Washington");
        states.add("West Virgina");
        states.add("Wisconsin");
        states.add("Wyoming");

        final
       ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states);
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                 adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                return false;
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView myText = (TextView) view;
        Toast.makeText(this, "You Selected "+ myText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Comment: rather than using spinner and textview just use autocomplete textview...it will solve your problem...refer this http://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example

Comment: @HetalUpadhyay I don't think that would work because  it has to be a drop down, and he wants the drop down to be empty unless you click the button, and if you enter no letters , he wants nothing to happen and if you enter 0 or more than 1 letter (i think he set that up so that you couldn't just do an auto complete text view), UNLESS, can set it up to control that fact?  But I had looked into that hopping...  but maybe there is a way to set up that part.  But yeah he specifically wants it on the button click and to only be able to enter 1 letter for it to do anything (the first letter)

Answer (score 1):

Ok...than do something like have an edittext and a button. on clicking button fill your adapter with filtered data.

For Ex.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Edittext
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Look for States below"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:textSize="30dp"
 />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search States"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>

<Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

In Java Code

```
public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
        Button button = (Button) v;
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayList states = new ArrayList();

        //fill your list with only matching criteria by any query


}
```

Comment: Thats similar to what I currently have except not using the searchQuery, so, I do believe it's the query part that I'm having the most trouble with.

Comment: yes...you are adding values to spinner without any filtering....you have to do some query before adding....and there is no need to listen search query event as you want only first charcter